# Unable to get the shared with me files with the Google Drive Api using Filters.sharedWithMe()

Tags: java, android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I have some files in my **Google Drive** that others have shared with me and I would like to be able to query them. Unfortunately the MetadataBuffer' result count is 0

This is the code:

```
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(com.google.android.gms.drive.Drive.API)
            .addScope(com.google.android.gms.drive.Drive.SCOPE_FILE).addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).build();

}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
    Query query = new Query.Builder().addFilter(Filters.sharedWithMe()).build();
    Drive.DriveApi.query(mGoogleApiClient, query).setResultCallback(metadataCallback);
}

private ResultCallback<DriveApi.MetadataBufferResult> metadataCallback =
        new ResultCallback<DriveApi.MetadataBufferResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(DriveApi.MetadataBufferResult result) {
                if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Problem while retrieving results");
                    return;
                }

                MetadataBuffer buffer = result.getMetadataBuffer();
                if(buffer != null) {
                    int cnt = buffer.getCount();
                    Log.d(TAG, "BUFFER COUNT: " + cnt);
                    for(int i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
                        Metadata meta = buffer.get(i);
                        Log.d(TAG, meta.getTitle());
                    }
                    buffer.close();
                }
            }
        };

        ....................
```

I am using the new Google Drive and I also tried moving some shared files from the ***Incoming Folder*** into the ***My Drive*** root. Still nothing. 
I would appreciate any help and suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said also on [unable to query the files "shared with me" from google drive using Google drive api android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26992251/unable-to-query-the-files-shared-with-me-from-google-drive-using-google-drive) , at the moment drive apis let you access only  data in drive made by your app.

you can verify by yourself by changing
    *Query query = new Query.Builder().addFilter(Filters.sharedWithMe()).build();*
in
    **Query query = new Query.Builder().build();**

and you see only one folder, named "App Data"

to access other files you need to use drive java api, as told in https://developers.google.com/drive/android/auth#connecting_and_authorizing_the_google_drive_android_api

> Note: The Google Drive Android API currently only supports drive.file and drive.appfolder 
>   authorization scopes. If your application requires additional permissions or features not 
>   yet available in the Drive Android API, you must use the Google APIs Java Client.